# New Docker Build secret information for use with aws cli

Tags: docker, aws-cli, docker-build

I would like to use the new [--secret flag](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) in order to retreive something from aws with its cli during the build process.

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental
FROM alpine
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,dst=/root/.aws cat /root/.aws
```

I can see the credentials when running the following command:

```
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain --secret id=mysecret,src=%USERPROFILE%/.aws/credentials .
```

However, if I adjust the command to be run, the aws cli cannot find the credentials file and asks me to do aws configure:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,dst=/root/.aws aws ssm get-parameter
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental
FROM alpine
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws,dst=/aws export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/aws aws ssm get-parameter ...
```